# how can i connect my mobile set with my asterisk ivr system

Tags: mobile, set, asterisk, ivr

i am trying to connect my mobile set(nokia N95) to my asterisk(ivr) system but each time i do sip configuration on my mobile set registration failed comes on my mobile set screen and some times it comes on my laptop screen in asterisk CLI "no matching peer found" as "registration failed" comes on mobile set screen

here are the settings of my system(sip file)

```
 [4007]
 username=4007
 type=friend
 secret=rock7
 host=dynamic
 callerid=4007
 context=default
```

following is what i am doing on my mobile set(nokia N95)

```
 Profile name=default
 Service profile=IETF
 Default access point=PTCL-BB  (where PTCL-BB is the wifi internet connection 
                                my mobile set and system are connected with)

 Public user name=sip:4007@192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3 ip address of my system)
 Use compression=No
 Registration=Always on
 Use security=No

 Proxy server settings:

 Proxy server address=sip:192.168.1.3
 Realm=192.168.1.3
 User name=4007
 Password=rook7
 Allow loose routing=Yes
 Transport type=Auto
 Port=5060

 Register server settings:

 Register server address=sip:192.168.1.3
 Realm=192.168.1.3
 User name=4007
 Password=rook7
 Transport type=Auto
 Port=5060
```

how can i fix this problem of registration of my mobile set? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why you just not google for settings? Here it is:

http://blog.laimbock.com/2008/02/25/nokia-n95-sip-and-asterisk-14/

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Now I solved it. First register your sip connection with Internet Call and make default setting to Internet calls.